# Migration assistant Mac applications

Tags: mac, migration, migration-assistant

I was only wondering how the Migration assistant for mac works, specially when you transfer Applications. Does it "reinstall" them with my preferences? Or maybe it's like a fresh install? Does it keeps all the updates I've installed on some of my apps?

Thanks for your explanations :)

Comment: As far as I know, *Migration Assistant* just copies the applications from the source disk and copies preferences (user and system). For most applications this should be transparent (it is not like a “fresh install” where updates and preferences might not be present). The most common exception is for applications that are locked to specific machines (the preferences and license are copied, but they may not be valid on a different machine).

Comment: thnks a lot, that sums it up well, you shouldn't have post this in answer, not in comment :)